# How can I call a symfony webAction using php sockets?

Tags: php, sockets, symfony1

I have a Symfony application working, which is a component that needs to be accessed by the main component of my website and by some external clients.

Currently, everyone is using cURL to interact with the component, but I figured it could be faster for me to use a socket based communication mechanism for the internal uses of the component.

Off course, I'd like to use the same webActions I use when I call the component as a regular client, is there any available plugin or something that might help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you should try the sfWebBrower plugin, it has a sfSocketsAdapter .

Comment: Hi: Thanks for your answer. It's an interesting plugin, though I think it won't be applicable for my particular problem, you see, what I want is to be able to accept requests coming through a socket interface, not send those requests (That will be another issue I'll have to deal with, but that part of the system is not based on symfony anyway...). So, what I want to know is wether I can "fool" the framework in order to receive it's request from sockets instead of webRequests.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean, this usage seems to be quite unusual, I couldn't find an plugin related to this. Good luck.